# Why do series NMOS do better than a single NMOS from a delay perspective?

Tags: semiconductors, vlsi, solid-state-devices, device-characteristics

My VLSI text (Weste and Harris) writes the following:

> Transistors in series drop part of the voltage across each transistor and thus experience smaller fields and less velocity saturation than single transistors. Therefore, series transistors tend to be a bit faster than a simple model would predict. For example, two nMOS transistors in series deliver more than half the current of a single nMOS transistor of the same width. This effect is more pronounced for nMOS transistors than pMOS transistors because nMOS transistors have higher mobility to begin with and thus are more velocity saturated.

It's not terribly clear to me but it seems like they are saying that, when discharging some effective capacitance at the output node of a given CMOS gate, the PDN does so more effectively (ceteris paribus, i.e. the PDN with the longer total length) if there are nMOS transistors in series. I'm not quite sure why this follows. I agree that, with the same overdrive voltage \$V_{ov}\$, lower \$V_{ds}\$ means higher \$I_d\$ because of minimized saturation effects. But as we discharge, the PDN that has series transistors leaves saturation first (and so current decreases) as compared with the PDN that does not have series transistors (is just a single transistor between output and ground). Given this, how can we say that a PDN with series transistors will do better? I agree it draws more current initially, but as the output discharges how does the argument from Weste and Harris still hold up?

Answer (score 1):

The idea here revolves around velocity saturation and how the electric field across the channel impacts the current through the device.

Key concepts:

1. **Velocity Saturation**: At a sufficiently high electric field, the carriers (electrons for nMOS and holes for pMOS) reach a maximum drift velocity, and further increases in the electric field do not result in an increase in drift velocity. In CMOS technology, especially at smaller technologies, the fields are often high enough that velocity saturation is a concern.
2. **Impact on Current**: The saturation of velocity can limit the drain current (Id). Remember, the current is a function of carrier mobility, electric field, and the number of available carriers. If the velocity is saturated (because the electric field is high), then the drain current might not increase linearly with an increase in Vds.

Now, when you have two transistors in series:

- Each transistor will have only a fraction of the total Vds across it.
- Therefore, each transistor will experience a lower electric field across its channel compared to a single transistor dropping the full Vds.
- As a result, the series transistors will be less affected by velocity saturation (or they may avoid it entirely for a more extended Vds range).

The intuition you're providing is accurate in that as Vds decreases (as you discharge the effective capacitance), the current will drop. However, the crucial point here is about *relative* behavior. For a single transistor, the high initial Vds might cause significant velocity saturation from the start, limiting its current. On the other hand, for series transistors, they might start with a high current (less affected by velocity saturation) and maintain a relatively high current for a more extended range of Vds, before they start seeing a sharp decline due to reaching their own saturation.

At its core, both the single transistor and the series transistors will experience a decrease in current when the output discharges. However, the series setup can sustain a higher current across a wider range of output voltages. This means it can discharge the effective capacitance more quickly.

Remember that the effects described are more pronounced in advanced technologies where channel lengths are small, and electric fields in the channel are high, leading to prominent velocity saturation effects. It's also worth noting that the series transistors will have increased resistance due to having two channels in series, but this effect might be outweighed by the benefits from reduced velocity saturation.

Comment: I guess what I am getting at is how we can make this claim about "series better" when the series transistors will have different \$V_{gs}\$ than the corresponding single transistor, as well as that eventually \$V_{ds}\$ for each series transistor will be relatively small (which means little current, even if there are no velocity saturation effects). It's not clear to me given these two levers that series should always be better, but perhaps I'd need to consult a different text to make that precise.

Answer (score 0):

I think my error was in misunderstanding how the discharge of two series transistors works. This misunderstanding is related to the subsequent Problem 2.2 (I will return to this).